# What does findHomography(par1, par2, par3) in opencv C++ returns

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

Hi i want to know what does the findHomography method do and the result it generates.
Can anyone give me good explanation of this method.

```
H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );
perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);
```

Comment: I can understand your desire to know more about it because it was a big black box when I used it in an application I made before. However, it's not a programming issue. It's a conceptual mathematics issue. You might get more success asking for a simplified explanation on the [mathematics stack exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/). I would love to see the answers. I hope this doesn't get modded - if you ask on math and link here, I think it would be a valuable addition to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[findHomography()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) returns [matrix of homography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29).

The `perspectiveTransform()` on the basis of this matrix gives you corners of the object inside the scene.

Comment: can u please explain me more about this, im new to this. thanks

Comment: @kevin I don't think that it can be explained shorter that in Wiki.